# What type of K-medoids is implemented in RapidMiner

Tags: cluster-analysis, rapidminer

I would like to know what type of K-medoids is implemented in RapidMiner? Is it PAM or some modification?

And what initialization does it use? Since I get the same results each time I run it.

I cannot find any information about it and I would like to know what I am working with and maybe implement it myself.

Comment: "Use the source, Luke." Instead of expecting us to do this for you.

Comment: http://fossies.org/dox/rapidminer-5.3.013/KMedoids_8java_source.html

Comment: Doesn't look as if it is PAM, or any published variant of k-Medoids; but an adaption of Lloyds algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how is it possible that I couldn't find it myself. Yes it looks like swap step is performed on cluster basis, for each cluster, per iteration. I was actually going for that idea myself, I found some paperwork about it. Do have any idea about quality of results of this approach? It seems much faster, but definitely "more local", so I wonder if it could give satisfying results with proper initialization step...

Comment: I'm not convinced of either k-means nor k-medoids for complex data. k-means is okay for e.g. color or signal quantization - it really does work there. But most other data is too noisy IMHO. You need an approach that doesn't require you to know k beforehand, and that does not force objects into clusters.

Comment: For the initialization, you can change this by setting the random seed. Two options are possible; either set it to a specific number in the k-medoids algorithm or set it to -1 in the main process context to get a different value for each run.